# how to force  image file and music file  to download with zip format in drupal 6?

Tags: entities, files

i have content type to upload music and image files.i want to provide a link to the users to download those music and image files.By using force download module , i can provide the download link for the file ,but now i want to zip the file when user click the download link and so user can download the image or music file in zip format.

i have installed the pclzip module and custom formatter module and i think we can achieve this by creating custom formatter for those cck field,but i dont know how to implement it? or any other module suggestion?  thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer with a question, do you want to make a zip file because it's an easy way to force browser to download the image or the mp3 instead of showing it ?

If so I'll recommend you the [File Force Download](http://drupal.org/project/file_force) module to achieve this. Also you have [DownloadFile](http://drupal.org/project/download_file) module and a .htaccess way to do this: [Force Files to Download Instead of Showing Up in the Browser](http://drupal.org/node/417866) but I don't find this one to be very flexible.

Comment: yes, i want to force files to download instead of showing up in the browser but i want to create zip file with the image and then force to download

Comment: File Force Download module will force the file to download but i want to download the file in Zip format.